# Как сделать перемещение текста из placeholder в fieldset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть первая картинка, если ткнуть в поле ввода текст из плейсхолдера перемещается в fieldset.
Как это сделать? Что используется?

[image: было]

[image: стало]

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если вы добавите хотя бы код оформления этого элемента. Чтобы было проще работать

Comment: Если это правда fieldset, то затык не ясен. Есть же legend

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Думаю у него проблема с анимацией, а не с тем что значение выставить в эту область

Comment: @EzioMercer, тогда это не плейсхолдер.

Comment: @Инквизитор Я и не утверждал обратного) Просто предплоложил, что ему нужна сама анимация перемещения, а не просто чтобы в `legend`-е появилось значение

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так можно сделать, только придется покумекать, как запретить тексту прыгать назад при потере фокуса инпутом. Но мне лень =)

```css
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 0px none;
  padding: 0 1em 0.25em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

legend {
  transform: translate(0, 18px);
  width: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: green;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition-duration: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus+legend {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  transform: unset;
  width: auto;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" />
  <legend>Номер заказа</legend>
</fieldset>
```